# Intuitive argument for symmetry of Lorentz boosts

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, matrix-elements

The Lorentz boosts are represented by symmetric $4\times4$ matrices. Though the most general Lorentz transformations has no obvious symmetry property, can the symmetry (under transpose) of the Lorentz boost matrices be understood intuitively? Like, from considerations of principle of relativity (that the inverse transformation can be obtained by the transformation $v\leftrightarrow-v$).

Comment: The 3+1-Lorentz  boosts come from the 1+1-Lorentz  boosts by a similarity transformation, more exactly by a pure rotation in space. This similarity preserves the symmetry. So, we must think intuitively why the 1+1-Lorentz  boosts are symmetric.

Comment: Kind of relevant, in that I discuss the symmetry &  linearity of the Lorentz transformations: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/562271/123208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that may be there exists any intuitive argument for the symmetry of Lorentz boosts. But at least I try to think as follows.

First consider the 1+1-Lorentz boost $\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
ct'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & L_{14}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
L_{41} & L_{44}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
ct\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{=}
\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}
\mathbf{X}
\tag{01}\label{01} 
\end{equation}
Since special relativity unifies space and time in an entity, an argument would be that the Lorentz boost \eqref{01} must be symmetric under exchange of $x$ and $ct$. So applying the matrix
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:0 & 1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1 & 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}\,,\qquad  \sigma^2_1\boldsymbol{=}\rm I
\tag{02}\label{02} 
\end{equation}
on equation \eqref{01} we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
ct'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:0 & 1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1 & 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
ct'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{=}
\overbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:0 & 1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1 & 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & L_{14}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
L_{41} & L_{44}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:0 & 1\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1 & 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}}^{\sigma_1 \mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\sigma_1} 
\begin{bmatrix}
ct\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{03}\label{03} 
\end{equation}
So we must have $\sigma_1 \mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\sigma_1\boldsymbol{=}\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}$ or
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1 \mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\boldsymbol{=}\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\sigma_1
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}
The Lorentz boost matrix $\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}$ must commute with the $\sigma_1 $ matrix (that the latter is a Pauli matrix is irrelevant here)
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{41} & L_{44}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
L_{11} & L_{14}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
L_{14} & L_{11}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
L_{44} & L_{41}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation}
From above equation
\begin{equation}
L_{14}\boldsymbol{=}L_{41} \quad \text{and} \quad L_{11}\boldsymbol{=}L_{44}
\tag{06}\label{06}
\end{equation}
So the matrix $\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}$ must be symmetric with equal elements on the diagonal. Setting
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\!\!L_{11}\boldsymbol{=}L_{44}\boldsymbol{=}\xi\ge 1 \:\:\texttt{(orthochronus)}     \:\text{and} \: L_{14}\boldsymbol{=}L_{41}\boldsymbol{=}\eta\stackrel{\det \mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\boldsymbol{=+}1}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=}}\boldsymbol{}\pm\sqrt{\xi^2-1}
\tag{07}\label{07}
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{L}_{_{2\times2}}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:\xi & \eta\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:\eta & \xi\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\,, \qquad  \eta\boldsymbol{=}\pm\sqrt{\xi^2-1}
\tag{08}\label{08}
\end{equation}
Given that $y'\boldsymbol{=}y,z'\boldsymbol{=}z $  the corresponding $4\times4$ matrix is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{L}_{_{4\times4}}\boldsymbol{=}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:\xi & \:\:0\:\:& \:\:0\:\:& \eta\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:0 & \:\:1\:\:& \:\:0\:\:& 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:0 & \:\:0\:\:& \:\:1\:\:& 0\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:\eta & \:\:0\:\:& \:\:0\:\:& \xi\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\,, \qquad  \eta\boldsymbol{=}\pm\sqrt{\xi^2-1}
\tag{09}\label{09}
\end{equation}
By a pure rotation in space we end up with a symmetric matrix for the Lorentz boost. To see how take a look in **SECTION B** of my answer as "user82794" here
[Two sets of coordinates each in frames O and O′ (Lorentz transformation)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200844/two-sets-of-coordinates-each-in-frames-o-and-o-lorentz-transformation).

Comment: This is rather nice! I like the answer. But two comments: 1. "Since special relativity unifies space and time in an entity, an argument would be that the Lorentz boost" see, you're arguing from conclusion! That the special theory of relativity unifies space and time is concluded from Lorentz transformation itself. So a bit circular. But I think I may be able to motivate this physically. So that's all good. 2. The determinant has to be positive if the time intervals in the transformed coordinates has to be positive.

Comment: @Faber Bosch : Your are absolutely right. I'm afraid that I bring an a posteriori result through the back door. That's why I think that  there does not exist any intuitive argument for the symmetry of Lorentz boosts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of understanding the group of Lorentz transformations: It is comprised of essentially two types of transformations, rotations in 3 dimensions and boosts. Hopefully rotations are familiar, so I will focus on understanding boosts. Specifically, I will talk about the boosts in the $x$-direction because a boost in any other direction can be constructed by first rotating the direction we want to boost along to point in the $x$-direction, apply a boost along the $x$-direction, and then rotate back.

With these things in mind, Lorentz boosts are the unique transformations $L(v)$ which satisfy the requirements to form a group, and two other conditions:

a) Boosting by zero does nothing: $L(0)=I$

b) Boosting by $-v$ is the same as the inverse boost: $L^{-1}(v)=L(-v)$

c) Associativity (follows automatically from dealing with matrices)

d) Closure: For any two velocities $u,v$ there exists some other velocity $w$ (we don't make any claims on what it should look like) such that $L(u)L(v)=L(w)$

e) Boosting by $v$ from stationary should make us move with velocity $v$: $L(v)\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}t^\prime\\ vt^\prime\end{array}\right)$ for some $t^\prime$ (again, no claims on what it should be).

f) The final condition is equivalent to the following: Suppose $P$ is the parity matrix, meaning it negates all the spatial directions. Then we should have
$$
PL(v)\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\end{array}\right)=L(-v)P\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\end{array}\right)=L(-v)\left(\begin{array}{c}t\\0\end{array}\right).
$$
In other words, applying a boost to a stationary frame and then applying parity should be the same as just applying a boost in the opposite direction.

With these conditions, the generic form of a boost along the $x$-direction is completely fixed except for a free constant, which is equivalent to the speed of light (and taking this constant to infinity gives back Galilean boosts too!).

The requirements are stated somewhat differently, but the steps to actually compute the Lorentz boost from the above data can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Using_group_theory).

Comment: There are two things I don't like about this. 1) Closure of the Lorentz transformations under multiplication is a big assumption and I do not see whether it can be argued from principle of relativity alone. 2) Likewise the wikipedia link that you've shared shows explicitly that the principle of relativity implies $\det{\Lambda}=+1$ (see the equation $\gamma^2+v\delta\gamma=1$), so I don't see how the thing about parity, which has negative determinant, could be concluded from principle of relativity unless it is assumed.

Comment: Moreover, I was not actually asking for a derivation of the Lorentz boosts. My question is whether the transpose symmetry can be invoked from the first principles.

Comment: @FaberBosch Closure under multiplication is equivalent to the statement that boosting and then boosting again is no different than boosting once by some amount (we do not assume what this amount is a priori). Personally, I find this to be a very natural assumption, but this is not the only derivation. The parity requirement is indeed an additional assumption, but note it is only a statement about the action on a single vector, so there is no contradiction coming from the determinants. Finally, I think I have to ask you to clarify what "transpose symmetry" is then. Boosts are not symmetric.

Comment: "Closure under multiplication is equivalent to the statement that boosting and then boosting again is no different than boosting once by some amount (we do not assume what this amount is a priori)" I understand what closure is and it is not at all an obvious or simple assumption to make. For example, boost along two different directions are not closed. What makes you think that it would be closed if the boosts are in the same direction? (If not hindsight) The reason is not at all obvious. One must either provide solid intuitive reasoning for closure or assume it. The matter is not trivial.

Comment: This is a fair point, though the example of boosts along other directions requires us to be in more than one spatial dimension. So long as the initial arguments in my answer are accepted, we have restricted to a 1+1 dimensional case. Here I think we can argue as follows: suppose there are 3 frames A, B, C. If boosts in 1+1 were not closed, then B's observation that C and A are both inertial would not imply A observes C to be inertial. This consequence seems rather strange to me, but perhaps you have another perspective.

Comment: Ok! But then the claim is that all the inertial frames are only connected by boosts. What if boosts are not closed, that is $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\not\equiv A\rightarrow C$ (arrow means boosts), but the transformation between $A$ and $C$ are still linear (meaning inertial). If one defines inertial to mean only boosts, then even translations will not preserve inertiallity. If that makes sense, I don't know.

Comment: I will have to think on this more, but certainly this is not the case in the low velocity limit. Given that additional piece of input data, there may be some continuity argument which extends "inertial frame" (meaning moving with constant relative velocity) to being an equivalence relation at arbitrary boost parameter. Perhaps this may feel like a cop out of you're looking to avoid as much experimental input as possible, but perhaps not. Nonetheless, it feels like failure of transitivity should lead to a contradiction in some way. Certainly closure follows if we involve the invariant interval.

Answer (score 1):

As Frobenius says in a comment, drop to the 1+1-D case. One dimension of time $w=ct$, one dimension of space $x$.

Then you want to preserve the velocity of light and this means $\hat w\pm \hat x$ are eigenvectors of the Lorentz transform: orthogonal (in the Euclidean sense) eigenvectors with real eigenvalues. So it’s Hermitian but it's real: so it's symmetric. Gives you the hint that it's not symmetric if you choose, say, $w=2ct$. But had you chosen $w=2ct$ the resulting matrix would still obey the inversion principle $L(v)L(-v)=I$ so that cannot be sufficient.

Now, that's kind of cheesy, you could say it needs to be “symmetrizable” in some sense, so let me give more substantial examples. First, the 2x2 rotation matrix by angle $\theta=\tan^{-1}(v/c)$ satisfies $R_\theta R_{-\theta}=I$, but $R_\theta$ is not symmetric. Second, the Galilean transformation matrix satisfies $G(v)G(-v)=I$ but it's not symmetric.

Looking at Richard Myers’ answer these appear to satisfy in addition all axioms (a)-(f) and he gives a hint that the second example corresponds to an infinite speed of light, so it seems plausible that the first example is instead something like an imaginary speed of light?

Answer (score 0):

The transformation matrix of the four-vectors in RR is:
$$ 
\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu} = 
\pmatrix{ \gamma  &  -{\gamma \over c} \bf{v}  \cr
  -\gamma {\bf{v} \over c}   &  \bf{L}  \cr } = 
\pmatrix{
  \gamma & {\gamma\over c}v_1 & {\gamma\over c}v_2 & {\gamma\over c}v_3  \cr
-{\gamma\over c}v_1 & 1+(\gamma-1){v_1^2\over v^2}  &   (\gamma-1){v_2v_1\over v^2} & (\gamma-1){v_3v_1\over v^2} \cr 
-{\gamma\over c}v_2 &   (\gamma-1){v_1v_2\over v^2} & 1+(\gamma-1){v_2^2\over v^2}  & (\gamma-1){v_3v_2\over v^2} \cr 
-{\gamma\over c}v_3 &   (\gamma-1){v_1v_3\over v^2} &   (\gamma-1){v_2v_3\over v^3} &1+(\gamma-1){v_3^2\over v^2} \cr }
$$

$\bf{L}$ is a space operator having eigenvectors $\parallel\bf{v}$ belonging to the eigenvalue $\gamma(v)$
and eigenvectors $\perp\bf{v}$ belonging to the eigenvalue $1$.
The symmetry of $\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}$ depends on the symmetry $ (x\leftrightarrow ct)$
of the standard Lorentz transformations:
$$ {R^\mu}' = \Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu} \, R^\nu \qquad\qquad
\pmatrix{ct' \cr x' \cr y' \cr z' \cr} =
\pmatrix{
\gamma & -{\gamma\over c}v & 0 & 0 \cr
 -{\gamma\over c}v & \gamma & 0 & 0 \cr
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \cr
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr } 
\pmatrix{ct \cr x \cr y \cr z \cr}
$$

To understand this symmetry it's appropriate to derive the above result
with a method due (I believe) to Ignatowsky (1910).
It's easy to see that, to safeguard the concept of inertial reference system, the coordinate
transformation formulae must be pre-formatted (with one indeterminate parameter $\gamma$) as follows:
$$
\eqalign{
& x' = \gamma (x - vt) \cr
& y' = y  \cr
& z' = z  \cr
& t' = \gamma \left[t-\left(1 - 1/\gamma^2 \right){x\over v} \right] \cr
}
$$
The only relevant assumption needed to obtain this result is that the inverse transformations
are gained by changing the sign of time, ie by changing the sign of the  relative speed
of the refernce systems $(\bf{v} \leftrightarrow \bf{-v})$.
Consistently the velocity transformation formula results
$$ u' = {u -v\over 1 - \left(1-{1\over \gamma^2} \right){u\over v}} $$

Such formulas are independent of any principle of relativity.
For $\gamma = 1$ they provide Galileo's transformations.

Let us now ask ourselves if there can exist a velocity $c$ invariant, that is
having the same value in all inertial reference systems:
$\forall v: u' = u =c$.
For $u'=u=c$ that implies:
$$ 1-{1\over \gamma^2} = {v^2 \over c^2} $$
If $\gamma > 1$ this relationship gives us a positive real value for $c$.
In this way we obtain the Lorentz transformations in standard configuration,
which have the required symmetry $ (x \leftrightarrow ct)$.

Conclusion: if and only if we admit the existence of an invariant velocity
the transformation matrices are symmetrical.
Therefore the symmetry of the matrix $\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu} $ can be seen as an expression
of the postulate of constancy of the speed of light.